Can I re-enter Germany with new passport & just Fiktionsbecheinigung (§81 Abs. 4) (ref lost passport no.) OR D-visa stamp required in new passport?
I am an Indian student studying at a Uni in Germany. Last month, I lost my passport (thereby my D-visa stamped in it got lost). However, the official at auslanderbehörder were kind enough to issue fiktionsbescheinigung so I can return back. The issued fiktionsbescheinigung says “Die inhaberin/der inhaber dieser Bescheinigung hat bei der unten genannten Behörde die Erteilung. Bie zur Entscheidung der Auslanderbehörder diesen antrag gilt der Aufenthaltstitels als fortbestehend beantragt (§81 Abs. 4 AufenthG)“. I traveled back to Indian on one-time use emergency passport issued by Indian consulate. I have also applied for a new passport and will be getting it in next couple of weeks.
My question is does this fiktionsbescheinigung refering old passport number (saying Aufenthaltstitels als fortbestehend beantragt (§81 Abs. 4 AufenthG)) with my new passport is enough to get entry into Germany (without a stamped D-visa)? Or I still need to get a D visa stamped inspite of having this fiktionsbecheinigung which clearly allows me re-entry to Germany?
I’ll appreciate your replies.

Do you have any documents that prove your previous passport (with the number mentioned in Fiktion) is lost?

I got a police report saying I lost my passport, and that report was submitted mandatorily for gaining single use Emergency passport from Indian consulate in Munich.
